# What are the functional differences between App ID URI and Return URLs in AzureAD app registrations?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are encountering an issue with AzureAD where the App ID URI cannot be set to a URL which is not a trusted domain

No such restriction applies to return URLs

Why are the restrictions different between these two functions? My understanding was that they were almost completely interchangeable

Comment: This query doesn't seem to meet SO guidelines refer - What types of questions should I avoid asking? - Help Center - Stack Overflow. Please ask your question on [MS Q&A] (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html).

Answer (score 0):

The **Application ID URI** is a globally unique URI used to identify the web API. As you said, it needs to be a verified customer-owned domain. All of the restrictions and best practices for the Application ID URI are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-best-practices-for-app-registration#application-id-uri).

The **Return URL** (or [Redirect URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-best-practices-for-app-registration#redirect-uri)) is just the URL where you want users to be returned to after they have authenticated. You can have multiple of these and the restrictions are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

Comment: Thanks, if you're a SaaS provider who needs customers to put a URL to an app into their own AzureAD whats the recommended way to go about it? We've explored making one of our subdomains trusted in the customer AzureAD, or make the customer bring their own domain name and SSL certificate.